# How can I take the password from the card and automatically transfer it to a form on another page?

Tags: python, django, forms, url-parameters

I have a history of generated passwords. Each password has its own frame with ID. Each password has login, website and date of creation in models ( Django Database). Of course when generating a password all fields except date and password are empty. On each password in the password history there is a "Save" button that would give some password a login and a website where it is used. I want that when I go to the form with saving, the password would be automatically written in the form for the corresponding field. In other words, on the history page I want to take the password id, and insert the required password, the id of which matches in the save field on the form page.

`history.html:`

```
<h2 class="text-center mb-4">Passwords History</h2>

          {% for password in passwords %}
          <div class="card text-center mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">Password ID {{ password.id }}</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ password.password }}</h5>
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ password.login }}</h6>
              <p class="card-text">{{ password.website }}</p>
              <a href="{% url 'save_pass' password.id %}" class="btn btn-info" >Save to your Passwords</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">{{ password.date }}</div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

In *history.html* every card of Password has its own "save" button. This button links to "save_pass" form in *save_pass.html* and gives the value of password.id in  `href="{% url 'save_pass' password.id %}"`

Then urls.py gets the `password.id` as a `password_id` variable using URL parametrs.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.home),
    path("password/", views.password, name="password"),
    path("about/", views.about),
    path("history/", views.history, name = "history"),
    path("save_pass/<int:password_id>/", views.save_pass, name = "save_pass"),
    path("saved_passwords/", views.saved_passwords, name = "saved_passwords")
]
```

Afterwards i get password_id in *views.py* in the in the corresponding function save_pass where i find the needed password object with the help of id:

```
def save_pass(request, password_id):
    password = get_object_or_404(Passwords, id=password_id)
    /* other code  */

    return render(request, "save_pass.html", {"password": password.password})
```

and it's all being sent to save_pass.html

`'save_pass.html:`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'save_pass' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class = "container">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login">Login:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value = "{{ password }}" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="website">Website URL:</label>
              <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" name="website" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Password</button>
        </div>
```

The problem is that i cannot access the website, because the are a bunch of stuff written in the console, but nothing related to my code. After i place href="{% url 'save_pass' password.id %}" in history.html this webpage cannot be launched and does not work at all.

This is only a small part of my console after trying to automatically paste the needed password in the form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRDIE.png)

If you have any questions about my other code parts then feel free to ask. I would welcome any help